# Rails 3.0: error with routes when overriding to_param in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm getting an error with my routes when I try to override to_param in my user model to use the email address as the id. It appears to be trying to match the entire object for the id when it tries to match the route. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing?

Here's the error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show", :id=>#<User id: 1, email: ....>}
```

Here's how I've set up the code.

models/user.rb:

```
attr_accessible :email    

def to_param 
  email
end
```

controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :get_user, :only=>[:show,:update,:edit,:destroy]

...

def get_user
  @user = User.find_by_email params[:id]
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
resources :users
```

And here's the output from rake routes:

```
     user GET    /users(.:format)          {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
          POST   /users(.:format)          {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"users", :action=>"edit"}
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"users", :action=>"update"}
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"users", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Comment: show you link, which leads to this error, please. All your code is right, so error is in your link

Comment: The problem is in show, edit, update, and destroy paths. So either trying to navigate to the path in the browser (/users/test@test.com, or calling link_to in the view, such as <%= link_to "Show", user %>, or <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(user) %>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the email adds a '.' (dot) in the url, and that confuses rails, because it tries to find a "com" format (if the email ends in .com)

I've added this code to one of my apps (I have People instead of Users) and it works properly, so the trick is to replace the dot with something else. I chose to replace it with an '@' as other symbols such as - or + are valid in email addresses.

file **person.rb**

```
def to_param
  email.sub ".", "@"
end

def self.param_to_email(param) 
  segments = param.split '@'
  host = segments[1..-1].join('.')
  segments[0] + '@' + host
end
```

file **people_controller.rb**

```
def get_person
  email = Person.param_to_email params[:id]
  @person = Person.find_by_email email
end
```

There are some more hints about how this works in http://jroller.com/obie/entry/seo_optimization_of_urls_in.

Thanks for the question, I'm just starting with rails, so this is really helping me to understand how it works :).

Comment: Thanks, Augusto! the blog post helped me understand the to_param situation a bit better. Still, I think there is something more going on here.. in my controller I am using find_by_email to find the user from the param, instead of the User.find. It seems to have a problem only with using the email in the route. I added a 'name' field to the user model just to test it, and it works fine to override to_param with the :name attribute, but email still fails, including if I prepend the id as per your suggestion. Any ideas why email specifically fails?

Comment: I found the problem. Please re-check the answer

Comment: Ah yes, I see in the error output when it shows the params it is parsing the '.com' part into this format argument. Thanks for the help figuring this out!

Answer (score 2):

You can include dots '.' in your to_param return value if you specify a custom regular expression for the 'id' parameter in your route, for example:

```
match '/images/:id',
  :via => :get,
  :constraints => { :id => /[^\/]+/ },
  :format => false,
  :to => 'images#show',
  :as => :image
```

See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered problems with sending email address trough GET.

```
#this url will cause the following problem
/resend-validation/abcd@abcd.com 
params[:email] = abcd@abcd

# I had to encode the email:
<%= link_to('Resend Code', resend_activation_path(:email => user.email.unpack('H*'))) %>

# than decode it in controller:
email = params[:email].split.pack('H*')
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems passing `'.' (dot)` through the URL you can add in your routes definition:

```
resources :users, :id => /.*/
```

credits to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943634/333061