# How to encode (.) Dot in url Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having routes like below to delete/list an user.

```
map.connect 'developer/:user_name/delete',:controller=>"developers",:action=>"delete",:method=>:delete  

map.connect 'developer/:user_name/list',:controller=>"developers",:action=>"list",:method=>:get
```

While listing the user by encoding the Dot with %2E, i can see the success response

```
http://localhost:3000/developer/testuser%2Ehu/list
```

But While trying to delete the user who containing the Dot(.), throws 404 error.

```
http://localhost:3000/developer/testuser%2Ehu/delete, how to fix this issue.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot is not allowed by default in Rails routing because the dot is considered the extension of the page. You should avoid using dots in URLs.

However, in your case you can instruct Rails to consider the dot for the `:user_name` parameter passing a regular expression.

```
map.connect 'developer/:user_name/list', :controller => "developers", :action => "list", :method=> :get, :user_name => /[\w.]+/
```

PS. Because of `map.connect`, you are using a very old version of Rails (Rails < 3). You should upgrade your application.

Answer (score 23):

Avdi Grimm wrote on this subject: http://avdi.org/devblog/2010/06/18/rails-3-resource-routes-with-dots-or-how-to-make-a-ruby-developer-go-a-little-bit-insane/

You'll want to do something like this (full credit to avdi)

```
  resources :users, :constraints => { :id => /.*/ } do
    resources :projects
  end
```

A commenter on the post says you can also do:

```
resources :users, :id => /.*/
```

Comment: That doesn't account for if you have another / in the url, such as `/search/hello+world/page/20`. Might be better to go with everything but a / with `/[^/]+/`

Comment: Worked great in Rails 4.2

Answer (score 9):

I just had a similar problem, my search page url is /search/search_term. When search_term had a dot, Rails interpreted it as the request format. If I tried to search for book.html, it actually searched for book, because Rails interpreted html as the format. An unrecognized format would return an error.

In my case, the first solution from Avdi Grimm didn't work, because my search is paginated, and the page number also goes in the url (/search/book/2). The solution for me was accepting everything but a slash for the search_term (the last solution from Avdi Grimm's post):

resources :users, :constraints => { :id => /[^\/]+/ }

Comment: I like your answer best, although I think that should be `/[^\/]+/`

Comment: Thanks, I actually typed the backslash, but it wasn't showing up on the page. I had to type 2 backslashes to show 1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a DELETE request to the delete url? Note that the route is defined with `:method=>:delete`, so it expects DELETE request (not GET).