# Dot causing error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a routes like this :

```
get ':user_name', to: 'profile#show', as: :profile
```

And the show method looks like this

```
before_action :set_user

def show
    @posts = @user.posts.order('created_at DESC')
end
def set_user
   @user = User.find_by(user_name: params[:user_name])
end
```

Everything seems fine . Like
If i go to `localhost/hello` its works.

But if i go to `localhost/hello.world` it gives error and says that `undefined method posts for nil:NilClass` And it also says

```
Parameters:

{"user_name"=>"hello",
 "format"=>"world"}
```

But we know `user_name` should be hello.world

Then why is this error ?? :(

Clearly I think this line is creating problem

```
 @user = User.find_by(user_name: params[:user_name])
```

How to fix it :( really annoying problem :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941462/how-to-encode-dot-in-url-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a combination of two problems:

1. You are using `find_by` instead of `find_by!`. The normal version won't raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFoundException when it can't find the record, which would gracefully make rails respond with a 404 and aport the before_action, which means `@user` ends up set to nil, and so you can't call `.posts` on it.
2. As @davidwessman has pointed out in the comments, you can't use dots by default on Rails routes. I suspect you have a record with name hello.world, but it's trying to find just hello and so it can't find anything.